# Ubuntu 20: Gedit missing from Activities Menu

Tags: 20.04, activities-overview

After I switched from Ubuntu 18 to 20, I lost the ability to open the text editor from the Activities menu.
If I doubleclick a text file, gedit is opened but if I try to open it by hand, I can't.
Gedit is installed but not available. I also reinstalled it with apt with no luck.

I tried typing: Text,Gedit, Write but got nothing. I'd like to be able to use and let other use the functionality of the Activities.

Comment: I guess its name is Text Editor now, and you can open it using the terminal by typing ``gedit``. If you don't like opening from a terminal you can create a keyboard shortcut for it

Comment: @preIdiot thx for answering. I know that I can access it with the terminal, I just want to be able to use (and let use) the Activities menu. I did try to use gedit/text/write or anything resembling to an editor but didn't get anything back. I edited the question for clarity

Comment: can you try searching org.gnome.gedit.desktop in your /usr/share/applications. If it is not there and you can create one

Comment: There is no version 18 or 20. I will guess from the flag you are using 20.04

Comment: @David you are correct.

Comment: @preIdiot the file exists. I noticed it defined all the keywords I tried and also plaintext, which wont work as well.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is, but until someone figures it out you can create your own .desktop file for gedit in /home/username/.local/share/applications..just create a textEditor.desktop file there and copy paste all the contents inside it...after that press alt+f2 and type r and enter then it will appear in activites

Comment: @preIdiot thanks for the the tip! I did copy the original file and gave it a new name (mytexteditor.desktop) and it worked even without restarting  the Activities! If you write it as an answer I can accept it even if it's not a bugfix. Note: If I remove my file, I can't find gedit anymore.

Comment: Ubuntu 18? Ubuntu 20?  No such releases. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  You have tagged a *yy.mm* release (20.04) but mention *snap* only specialist releases in your heading & description - please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work Around option

Copy-paste content of original gedit.desktop file to a new .desktop file

Open the terminal and do

`cd ~/.local/share/applications`

`sudo cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop textEditor.desktop`

:))

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it will help many other people and it will get fixed. (weird issue though)

Comment: also I did the hardcore solution : cd /usr/share/applications/; sudo cp org.gnome.gedit.desktop mytext.desktop

Comment: the terminal way is actually better than the physical 

Answer (score 0):

## Just Another Workaround

Just copy and paste this one-liner in your terminal. No need for `sudo`.

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop
```

Okay so there are workarounds, but the real question is, why did it disappear in the first place?